# Why cannot send just one post comment in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I am trying to write a PHP project.In this site people can share photos by logining and the photos are displayed in the index.php that is the main page of the program.Now I have three database users images and messages.I can provide users to share their photos by saved the information about the photos, and then get them from the database from images table.Now I want to provide a user to make a comment about a photo in the main page.There are textarea and post button under the images.But when I make a comment for an image it is registered not only related picture id but also for the other picture ids.Why does this happen?

Here is the some part of the php code, I also open and close the database connection in the necessary parts.

```
 while($x < mysql_num_rows($result))
        {   
      $picid=mysql_result($result, $x, 'id');
      $name=mysql_result($result, $x, 'imageName');
      $date=mysql_result($result, $x, 'imageDate');

        echo "<div><img src = 'upload/$name' height='300 width='300' /></div>";
        echo "Name: $name   Date: $date";
        echo "<br/>";
       ?>
       <p>Post a Comment</p>

      <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
      <textarea name="message" cols="70" rows="6" placeholder="Enter a comment">

     </textarea><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" style="float:left"><br/><br/>    
      <br/>
      </form>
     <!--<textarea name="message" cols="70" rows="6" ></textarea><br/><br/><br/><br/>   
     <br/><br/>-->
       <?php

        extract($_REQUEST);
        if (isset($submit)) {
          $y=0;
          $email=$_SESSION['email'];
           $asdf = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE email='$email'");
           //var_dump(mysql_error());
            while( $y<mysql_num_rows($asdf) )
           { 
            $iduser=mysql_result($asdf,$y,'id');
             $y++;
          }

               echo "$iduser";
               $sql ="INSERT INTO messages (id_user, message,picid) VALUES   
               ('$iduser','$message','$picid');";

               $rslt = mysql_query($sql);

               if ($rslt== false) {
                echo '<p>Error: cannot execute query</p>';
               }

              } ?>
              <?php

      $x++;

    }
```

Comment: yourpage.com?message='); DELETE * FROM messages#

Comment: Why is it in a while loop.

Comment: @Orangepill the first while to get the number of photos from the database images table.The second one for which user is posting this comment, to find the user from users table with matching the current user.

Comment: @GungFoo What do you mean by  DELETE * FROM messages# ?

Comment: do `echo $sql` to check if your insert query is correct or not.. Also share the query before the first `while`

Comment: @user1548222 [You are vulnerable to SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @draxxxeus I checked the sql but it is not the problem.:(How can I share it I couln't understand.

Comment: @draxxxeus It succesfully gets the images by the first while.Can be the reason to include form for each image with the same form information, name=message or name=submit?Because there are more than one form in the page.Maybe the program doesn't understand from which form this message is coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($x < mysql_num_rows($result)) {   
      $picid=mysql_result($result, $x, 'id');
      $name=mysql_result($result, $x, 'imageName');
      $date=mysql_result($result, $x, 'imageDate');

        echo "<div><img src = 'upload/$name' height='300 width='300' /></div>";
        echo "Name: $name   Date: $date";
        echo "<br/>";
       ?>
       <p>Post a Comment</p>

      <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
      <textarea name="message" cols="70" rows="6" placeholder="Enter a comment">
     </textarea><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      <input tyep='hidden' name='pic_id' value='<?php= $picid; ?>' />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" style="float:left"><br/><br/>    
      <br/>
      </form>
   <?php
  $x++;

    }
 ?>
```

This is generate the form and with the pics and when you submit the form, you will get the `pic_id` and the `message` in the `post` and you already have the `email` in the `$_SESSION`.

now, try to insert.

Comment: is it true to write <input type='hidden' name='pic_id'... in between textarea tags because when i try it, <input type='hidden' name='pic_id'...  is written in the textarea.:(

Comment: That was a typo from my side. Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Better you Should try AJAx for commenting system, you are getting this problem probably because of this code-

```
$asdf = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE email='$email'");
           //var_dump(mysql_error());
            while( $y<mysql_num_rows($asdf) )
           { 
            $iduser=mysql_result($asdf,$y,'id');
             $y++;
          }
```

Comment: but by this code I  just associated the user with the related picture because which user makes the comment is necessary for me.How can I use Ajax I don't know how to covert it.:(

Comment: You can maintain iduser (i.e., unique id of a user) too in the session then you just retrieve it from there, whenever you need it. You will not need to do an additional query to find it from database everytime.

Comment: The question by the OP is not how to send the request. AJAXifying will not solve the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a while loop  `while($x < mysql_num_rows($result))` that do inserts until end of the condition.

Giving all $picid in `$picid =mysql_result($result, $x, 'id');` and since isset($submit) is true, the program will insert the message in all rows.

Comment: yes but how can I approach this problem to solve it, to send the comment just the related picid?

Comment: you must know the "<input type="hidden" name="picid" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/>" for the message.

Comment: you must know the "<input type="hidden" name="picid" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/>" for the message. like $postpicid = $_POST["picid"] and $postmessage = trim($_POST["message"]) ... $lengthmessage = strlen($postmessage).... if lengthmessage < 1 dont do the insert

Comment: where I should this "<input type="hidden" name="picid" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/>.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you're executing your INSERT statement inside your `while` loop. That means when they submit the form, your output loop (the top `while`) is going to retrieve records, and while it's building the HTML output, it's going to execute an INSERT *for each output record*. The `$picid` variable is being set to the next picture ID as the `while` goes through output records. But the `INSERT` is running inside that loop, adding the same comment to each `$picid`.

Let's leave aside that there are much cleaner ways to write this code. Either you're a novice programmer or don't have much control over the structure of your project - neither of which is a negative thing, but let's stick with what you have for now.

Even within the structure you have, this code needs to change significantly.

```
while($row < mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  // $row is an array with all the columns, 
  //   No need to keep calling a separate function to get the columns.
  //
  //$picid=mysql_result($result, $x, 'id');
  //$name=mysql_result($result, $x, 'imageName');
  //$date=mysql_result($result, $x, 'imageDate');

    echo "<div><img src = 'upload/{$row['name']}' height='300 width='300' /></div>";
    echo "Name: {$row['name']}   Date: {$row['date']}";
    echo "<br/>";

  // Notice the new <input> tag in the FORM below. 
  // You still need to identify which picid to add the message to.
 ?>
   <p>Post a Comment</p>

  <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="picid" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/>
    <textarea name="message" cols="70" rows="6" placeholder="Enter a comment">
    </textarea>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" style="float:left">
    <br/><br/><br/>
  </form>

   <?php
} // END RESULTS OUTPUT (while)

// BEGIN SUBMIT DATA PROCESSING
if (isset($submit))
{
  // This is not recommended, but it's not the point here.
  extract($_REQUEST);
  //$y=0;
  $email=$_SESSION['email'];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE email='{$email}'");

  // Unless an email can have multiple records in [users] table, 
  // the loop is unnecessary.
  //while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  //{ 
    // $row is an array with all the columns, 
    //   No need to keep calling a separate function to get the columns.
    // $iduser=mysql_result($asdf,$y,'id');
    //     $y++;
  //}
  // Instead... This automatically gets the first row from $result.
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $iduser = $row['id'];

  //echo "$iduser";
  $sql ="INSERT INTO messages (id_user, message,picid) VALUES   
    ('{$iduser}','{$message}','{$picid}');";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if ($result === false)
  {
    echo '<p>Error: cannot execute query</p>';
  }
} // END IF isset($submit)

?>
```

This is untested, but hopefully it'll get you going in a better direction.